# Android: Is there any specific place on the document to find explicit XML reference?

Tags: android

Android documentation for XML is too hard to find. Whatever I get is all Java related documents. I am a newbie to Android and trying to find XML references for Views and Widgets. For now, I am searching for [Checkbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox) but it I am struggling to get XML reference every time for any component.

Can anyone help me to learn how to find and use the reference documents especially for XML and its attributes?

Million thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML attributes are referred;

[image]

The CheckBox is created from inheriting CompoundButton, TextView etc.
Each view has its own XML attributes. So for CheckBox all the inherited values are applicable. For instance ChackBox has Button bahaviour, TextBox behaviour etc. Hence all above apply for the CheckBox. So if you want to add Button related behavior of CheckBox refer above 'Button Attributes'. If you want to add Text related behavior of CheckBox refer above 'TextView Attributes' etc.

Also refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable

Sample layout xml as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llMainFill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvLog"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:visibility="invisible" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and somewhat I understood but what I don't understand that how can I determine which attributes I can use within the XML. All of these attributes in docs looks like for Java to me. While I am looking or trying to understand about XML specific attributes which I can use within XML code and not Java. All these references I believe to be used in Java.

Comment: If you click the above 'TextView Attributes' it shows XML syntax. For instance 'android:textSize' etc.

Comment: Please check the above updated XML sample script, which has 'android:' properties etc.